# Validating object's type at runtime using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, runtime, typescript-generics

For a project I am currently working on, an SDK for consuming a backend API (written in Go), I would like to implement runtime type checking. As I've worked intensively with Typescript over the last couple of years, I know type safety is not guaranteed at runtime, as all type annotations will get lost during the compilation stage.

I have some projects using Typescript as a production dependency, to for example generate custom JSON decoders to allow code generation to take place based on Typescript interfaces: https://github.com/PicnicSupermarket/aegis.

A thought that came to mind, was using Typescript as a dependency and use it to check against an interface, but as I'm not really familiar with the structure of the Typescript compiler, I don't know what's possible.

So my question is: **is it possible to take a Javascript object, together with a Typescript interface, and validate whether the Javascript object satisfies the Typescript interface**? And if that can be done by calling the Typescript compiler as a production dependency somehow.

To give some further context, this is the function where results pass through in the SDK I am working on:

```
const throwOrReturn = <T>(result: APIResult<T>): T => {
    if (result.error) {
        throw new Error(result.error);
    }
    // We can assume that data is valid (type T) if no error was found
    return result.data as T;
};

interface APIResultSuccess<T> { data: T; error?: undefined; }
interface APIResultFailure { data?: undefined; error: string; }
type APIResult<T> = APIResultSuccess<T> | APIResultFailure;
```

Before `return result.data as T;` I would like to check whether `result.data` is valid if assigned type `T` at runtime. So currently I am using generics, but taking the checking one layer up, where I have access to the actual interface, instead of a generic, would not be an issue.

An example of how the `throwOrReturn` is implemented:

```
interface ReturnValues {
    // Some interface code
}

const exampleCall = async (config: Config): Promise<interface> => {
    const res = await get<interface>(config, GetEndpoints.EndpointWeNeed); // Wrapper for making API calls and 4xx/5xx error handling 
    return throwOrReturn(res);
};

export default exampleCall;
```

Comment: TypeScript types are erased. The purpose of TypeScript is to provide validation statically, when you are writing code.

Comment: Might this be what you're looking for? https://github.com/spotify/ts-interface-loader I'm also looking for a way to check interfaces at runtime and I recall seeing something a couple of months ago. If I find it, I'll post it here if the `ts-interface-loader` doesn't do it. I'm not sure I want to mess with `webpack` right now.

Comment: @tim.rohrer I found a working solution, if you're interested, https://medium.com/bytecodeagency/runtime-json-type-checks-with-typescript-interfaces-379e8ea81258?source=friends_link&sk=489009cb893e8a700956d9e51ff855d7 or the Github example project https://github.com/lucianonooijen/ts-runtime-json-checks-example